# Write a query to display EMPLOYEES having ID 101,102,103 as per the below order

Tags: sql

Write a query to display EMPLOYEES having ID 101,102,103 as per the below order:

1. 101
2. 103
3. 102

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment. What is your question?

Comment: This looks like homework. Stack Overflow is not a homework delivery service, you are expected to make a reasonable attempt and by all means ask for help with a specific problem. Please read [How to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: You can use case expression in the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you post your question more clear.
If I understood correctly, I think that you need something like this:

```
select 
       id, 
       listagg(employee_name,'-') within group (order by employee_name asc) as employee_name_list
  from employee
  group by id
  order by id asc
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I got the answer because This question already has been answered.